# SSH Handshake on Cisco IOS XE

Tags: ssh, rsa, ecc, ecdsa

I've configured the following on my IOS XE device.

```
!
ip ssh rsa keypair-name my-4096rsa-ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh server algorithm mac hmac-sha2-512 hmac-sha2-256
ip ssh server algorithm encryption aes256-gcm aes256-ctr
ip ssh server algorithm kex ecdh-sha2-nistp521 ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ip ssh server algorithm hostkey rsa-sha2-512 rsa-sha2-256
ip ssh server algorithm authentication keyboard
ip ssh server algorithm publickey ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
!
```

When I capture the traffic using Wireshark I see that the KEX Host key type is ssh-rsa.

[image: Wireshark Capture highlighting KEX host key type]

Since the only configured algorithms configured for Hostkey are rsa-sha2-512 and rsa-sha2-256 I'm curious why this is showing.  This hostkey type is not configured and before I dig in with TAC I wanted to see if anyone had any ideas why this would be the case.

Thanks for any insight,
Tim

Comment: This looks like a product support question for Cisco.

Comment: The newer rsa-sha2 _algorithms_ re-use the _key_ format, and type, of ssh-rsa; see [RFC8332 section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8332#section-3)

Answer (score 1):

*ssh-rsa* can mean multiple things in SSH2.

**ssh-rsa as public key algorithm**

The public key algorithm "ssh-rsa" is deprecated, which is used as part of host key verification and for user authentication, because signing and verification is performed with a SHA1 hash which is insecure.

**ssh-rsa as public key format**

The public key format "ssh-rsa" is not related to SHA1. This format is used for the public host key and for the client public keys. The **ssh-rsa** public key format is **not deprecated**

The **ssh-rsa public key format is secure** as long as you choose a sufficient key length >= 3096bits

Note: ssh-rsa keys with 3096bits are the default key settings from OpenSSH. So this should be a good recommendation.

**Explanation of the Wireshark dump**

With the command

```
ip ssh server algorithm hostkey rsa-sha2-512 rsa-sha2-256
```

only the public key algorithms are configured. The host key format is not affected.

During the host key verification, the public key is sent to the client. The mentioned **ssh-rsa** in the **Host key type** fild is the **public key format** and not the public key algorithm.

In your example, you are generating a RSA key (ssh-rsa):

```
ip ssh rsa keypair-name my-4096rsa-ssh-key
```

This is the reason, why the `Host key type` is `ssh-rsa`.